# object is not getting removed from list onCheckedChange listener of check box

Tags: java, android, arraylist, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

I have a list of contacts. I have a check box to select the contacts. These selected contacts I want to add in another list called invitation array list. I have created a method to add all contacts in invitation list if check box is selected called as toogleContactsSelection. This I am using in an activity.

I have created another method to add contacts in invitation arraylist if check box is selected.

Now I want to remove the object from an invitation array list if check box is unchecked i.e onCheckChangeListener of check box.

But object is not getting removed from invitationArrayList.

Adapter:

```
     public class InviteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InviteAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList;
        private Context mContext;
        public ArrayList<Invitation>  invitationArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView name;
            private CheckBox checkBox;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textContactName);
                checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            }
        }

        public InviteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList) {
            this.contactArrayList = contactArrayList;
            this.mContext = context;

        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.invite_contact_item, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Contact contact = contactArrayList.get(position);
            holder.name.setText(contact.getmFullName());

            holder.checkBox.setChecked(contact.getSelected());

            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                    if(b)
                    {
                        invite(contact);

                        Log.e("inviteList",String.valueOf(invitationArrayList.size()));
                    }
                    else {
                        invitationArrayList.remove(contact);

                        Log.e("inviteList",String.valueOf(invitationArrayList.size()));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return contactArrayList.size();

        }

        public void toggleContactsSelection( boolean isSelected ) {
            for( Contact contact : contactArrayList ) {
                contact.setSelected(isSelected);

                    invite(contact);

            }
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // OR you can use notifyItemRangeChanged - which ever suits your needs
        }

        public void invite(Contact contact)
        {

            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserId", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String mUserId = sharedpreferences.getString("userId","");

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            Invitation invitation = new Invitation();

            invitation.setSender_id(mUserId);
            invitation.setDate(date);
            invitation.setInvitee_no(contact.getmMobileNo());
            invitation.setStatus("0");
            invitation.setUser_name(contact.getmUserName());

            invitationArrayList.add(invitation);

        }

        public void removeInvite(int position)
        {
            invitationArrayList.remove(position);
        }

        public ArrayList<Invitation> getArrayList(){
            return invitationArrayList;
        }

    }


What is going wrong?

EDIT:

This is an adpater :


   public class InviteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InviteAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList;
    private Context mContext;
    public ArrayList<Invitation>  invitationArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        private CheckBox checkBox;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textContactName);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        }
    }

    public InviteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList) {
        this.contactArrayList = contactArrayList;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.invite_contact_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Contact contact = contactArrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.name.setText(contact.getmFullName());

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(contact.getSelected());

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if(b)
                {
                    invite(contact);

                    Log.e("inviteList",String.valueOf(invitationArrayList.size()));
                }
                else {

                    contactArrayList.get(position).setSelected(false);
                 //   holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                  // updateInvites();
                    Log.e("inviteList",String.valueOf(invitationArrayList.size()));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactArrayList.size();

    }
    public void setChecked()
    {
        for( Contact contact : contactArrayList ) {


        }
    }


    public void toggleContactsSelection( boolean isSelected ) {
        for( Contact contact : contactArrayList ) {
            contact.setSelected(isSelected);

                invite(contact);

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged(); // OR you can use notifyItemRangeChanged - which ever suits your needs
    }

    public void invite(Contact contact)
    {

        Invitation invitation = new Invitation();

            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserId", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String mUserId = sharedpreferences.getString("userId", "");

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            invitation.setSender_id(mUserId);
            invitation.setDate(date);
            invitation.setInvitee_no(contact.getmMobileNo());
            invitation.setStatus("0");
            invitation.setUser_name(contact.getmUserName());
            invitation.setContact_id(contact.getContactId());

            invitationArrayList.add(invitation);

    }
    public ArrayList<Invitation> getArrayList(){
        return invitationArrayList;
    }

    public void updateInvites(){
        invitationArrayList.clear();
        for(Contact contact : contactArrayList){
            if(contact.getSelected()){

                invite(contact);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an activity's code:

```
  sendInvites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mAdapter.updateInvites(); // updating list on sendInvites, 

            invitationArrayList = mAdapter.getArrayList();

            Log.e("inviteList",String.valueOf(invitationArrayList.size()));

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String toServer = gson.toJson(
                    Collections.singletonMap("invitations", invitationArrayList)
            );

            new SendMultipleInvitesAsyncTask(InviteContactsActivity.this,InviteContactsActivity.this).execute(toServer);

            finish();
            Intent i = new Intent(InviteContactsActivity.this,InviteContactsActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Now I am updating list onSendInvites, but when I check or uncheck the api it dose not behave as expected.

Comment: you can setTag(position) to check box and get it position and remove item on same position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so there are few silly mistakes I say,

a. Replace

```
final Contact contact = contactArrayList.get(position);
```

with

```
final Contact contact = contactArrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```

b. You are adding Object of Class `Invitation`

```
Invitation invitation = new Invitation();
    invitation.setSender_id(mUserId);
    invitation.setDate(date);
    invitation.setInvitee_no(contact.getmMobileNo());
    invitation.setStatus("0");
    invitation.setUser_name(contact.getmUserName());

    invitationArrayList.add(invitation);
```

c. You are trying to remove object of Class `Contacts`

```
else {
                    invitationArrayList.remove(contact);

                    Log.e("inviteList",String.valueOf(invitationArrayList.size()));
                }
```

**Solution**

in onBindViewHolder

```
   holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            contactArrayList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(b);
            Log.e("inviteList",String.valueOf(invitationArrayList.size()));
            }
        });
```

then make a method like

```
private void updateInvites(){
    invitationArrayList.clear();
    for(Contacts contacts : contactsArrayList){
        if(contacts.isSelected()){
             invite(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

> here `contact.setSeletected(boolean status)` and `contact.isSelected()` are setters and getters respectively

EDIT:
[Here is the link to my blog on RecyclerView which explains most of the concepts of Simple RecyclerView.](http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/#responding_user_actions)

Comment: where to use updateInvites()? I dint get it Plz can you explain in detail? @Mohammed Atif

Comment: update invites will be the last method you will call. just before using the invitationArrayList

Comment: For suppose you are using `invitationArrayList()` to make an API call. call this method `updateInvites()` just before making the call. this will update your invite list with the objects that are selected, and then you can use this updated list to make the call.

Comment: can you please check edited question? @ Mohammed Atif

Comment: NO, thats not how you are supposed to implement `updateInvites()`. Don't put this method call at place which is dynamically changing. If you have anything similar to done button, put it there. And I added a link of my blog on RecyclerView in the answer, you can view that too to see how to update lists on user response.

Comment: If I am using it on send button then too, as array list is getting clear in updateInvite method, then the list becomes 0 though check boxes are checked. @Mohammed Atif

Comment: invitationList is cleared, then for loop is written, so that new entries are present in the list. Can you please Update your new code completely under EDIT label. I guess you are doing something wrong

Comment: I updated the solution, once revise the `onItemCheckedListener` code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125127/discussion-between-mohammed-atif-and-sid).

Answer (score -1):

instead of using object to remove use index to remove item:

```
   invitationArrayList.remove(position);
```

it will work.

You are getting index out of bound because there may be possibility user is removing the item before adding it. may be particular element in not present in your invitationArrayList. So for this try this code:

```
if (invitationArrayList!=null && invitationArrayList.size() > 0 && invitationArrayList.size() > position +1){
 invitationArrayList.remove(position);
}
```

Comment: I tried using that but it gave me indexOutOfBound exception. @Anjali

Comment: no its not working, it dose not go into if condition. @Anjali

Comment: yes obviouslly it will not go inside your list if it doesn't contain that object